# rails 7 stimulus controller dont work at all on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, stimulusjs

in development everything work fine, but in heroku it don't work. I even add to HTML as wrote in stimulus docs:

```
<div data-controller="hello">
  <input type="text">
  <button>Greet</button>
</div>
```

and add to hello_controller.js in connect()

```
console.log("it works")
```

and even this don't work on heroku(in console also). Importmap, index.js, application.js, manifest.js seems good:

manifest.js:

```
//= link_tree ../images
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
//= link_tree ../../javascript .js
//= link_tree ../../../vendor/javascript .js
//= link custom.css
```

index.js:

```
// Import and register all your controllers from the importmap under controllers/*

import { application } from "controllers/application"

// Eager load all controllers defined in the import map under controllers/**/*_controller
import { eagerLoadControllersFrom } from "@hotwired/stimulus-loading"
eagerLoadControllersFrom("controllers", application)

// Lazy load controllers as they appear in the DOM (remember not to preload controllers in import map!)
// import { lazyLoadControllersFrom } from "@hotwired/stimulus-loading"
// lazyLoadControllersFrom("controllers", application)
```

application.js:

```
import { Application } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

const application = Application.start()

// Configure Stimulus development experience
application.debug = false
window.Stimulus   = application

export { application }
```

importmap.rb:

```
pin "application", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "turbo.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js", preload: true
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"


pin "popper", to: 'popper.js', preload: true
pin "bootstrap", to: 'bootstrap.min.js', preload: true
```

in application.html.erb related to js only:

```
<%= javascript_importmap_tags %>
```

there is only one clue:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "application". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

it shouldn't appear in chrome but it appears in production. Heroku logs show that everything fine, when deploying also everything fine except:

```
Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
Process exited with status 143
```

but google say it not big problem. Here additional gem that i added:

```
gem "devise", "~> 4.8"
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 5.1.3'
gem "sassc-rails"
gem "rails-controller-testing"
gem "will_paginate", "~> 3.3"
group :production do
  gem "pg", "1.3.5"
end
```

Will appreciate for any help

Answer (score 0):

My educated guess is that Heroku is using the production adapter from config/cable.yml, which asks for redis.